# How "doubtLESS" and "NO doubt" lost their literal sense, and now suggest probability or concession?

Tags: etymology

"NO doubt" literally has NO in it! doubtLESS has LESS in it! They both mean NO probability and NO concession. How can "doubtless", "no doubt" "merely suggest probability or concession"?

> **doubtless, no doubt, undoubtedly.** Doubtless, as an adverb, and no doubt have lost the literal sense of “without doubt.” Now they merely suggest probability or concession, as in *The court doubtless considered the possibility* and *No doubt other*

Bahrych, Merino. *Legal Writing and Analysis in a Nutshell 5th edition* (2017). 362.

Comment: If I had to take a guess I'd say it's because of people being patronizing/acquiescent to other people. You agree with what they are saying to avoid getting into an argument: "No doubt you're right, bro, no doubt," but you don't actually mean it that strongly. What you really mean is "Sure, whatever you say, I guess." Hence the phrase has come to mean that instead over time XD

Answer (score 1):

> Doubtless:
> *is used to mean that you are certain that something will happen or is true*
>
> They will doubtless protest, but there's nothing they can do.
>
> Doubtless you have heard the news already.
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/doubtless)

In these examples, *doubtless* appears as an adverbial qualifier based on opinion rather than fact. The assertion appears certain, but is (at least in principle) left open to negation.

This usage contrasts with related statements such as “There is no doubt that they will protest” or “There is no doubt that you have heard the news”, which are statements of certainty, presumably based on some proven or incontrovertible facts.

This slight shift of meaning between the different constructions is consistent with the flexibility of language and the development of idiom.

There is no doubt that you have read this answer. No doubt the answer helps with your question.